# Ways to calculate the color range for a given mask

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using Python with OpenCV and I have the following code, which will calculate the "mean color" for a given contours/img.

```
mask = np.zeros((img.shape[:2])
out = cv.drawContours(mask, dtype=np.uint8), contours, -1, color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=cv.FILLED)
mean = cv.mean(img, mask=mask)
```

What I wish is that, instead of calculating the "mean color", **I would get some sort of color range derived by the masked area which derived from the contours.**
I'm open to any algorithm/color system even if they are not available in OpenCV.

Comment: Please define "color range", and add a sample image, and give an example. Each color has R,G,B component, so there are three ranges (R range, G range and B range). Are you asking for 3 ranges? Does the range apply the minimum and maximum of each color component? Note that "some sort of color range" requires too much guessing.